# React Local Server not starting

Tags: reactjs

Whenever i try to create a new react app, it always shows this error, i even cloned a repo but it is still the same error it throws

The command in the terminal is
`npx create-react-app myapp`

and the error logged is

```
'k' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1078
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\create-react-app\index.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1075:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:920:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.16.0
```

What can be done in this situation?

Comment: I've never seen such an error running that command; it seem like a typo, but then if it's not, googling it doesn't show any specific `'k'` error results so .. on top of my head can you try running `npm uninstall -g create-react-app` and then re-running the `npx create-react-app appname` command? What happens? If not then, what's the `npm -v`?